# Create enum from an attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I'm marking my enums with an own entity attribute used to map the enums to the corresponding field in a case management system.

Getting the correct string from an enum value works fine, but how can I generate an enum from a string?

I started by doing this:

```
foreach (var fieldInfo in enumType.GetFields())
{
    var attribute = (EntityNameAttribute)fieldInfo
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (EntityNameAttribute), false)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (attribute == null)
        continue;

    if (attribute.Name != name)
        continue;

    //got a match. But now what?
}
```

But how do I get the proper value from a field? Can I just use `fieldInfo.GetValue`? If so, what instance should I use? Should the enum be treated as a static type?

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean by *"generate enum by string"*. Do you mean to say `"Red" => Color.Red` by any chance?

Comment: @MunimAbdul: A state can be named "01 - Planning" in the other system, which means that I got `[EntityName("01 - Planning")]Planning = 1,` as a field in my enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
```

They're just static readonly fields, effectively. Note that that *isn't* getting an enum from a string... but if you *do* need to do that, you can use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx).

One thing to note - if you're using .NET 3.5, your whole code can be simplified with LINQ:

```
var values = from field in enumType.GetFields()
             from EntityNameAttribute attribute in 
                   field.GetCustomAttributes((typeof(EntityNameAttribute), false)
             where attribute.Name == name
             select field.GetValue(null);
```

(That's assuming that if there *are* multiple attributes of the right type defined, you don't care which one has the right name, and only one *will* have the right name.)

Comment: @jgauffin: No need to feel silly at all. Perfectly reasonable question :)

Comment: +1 wrote what I wanted to... only in a more concise, informative and elegant fashion..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be treated as a static type:

```
string enumString = fieldInfo.GetValue(null).ToString();
```

will work